# My RegSetValueA function is returning ERROR_SUCCESS but not working

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

My code:

```
    HKEY hKey;
    char *path = "SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\IDConfigDB\\Hardware Profiles\\0001";
    LONG result1 = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
    QString q = QString::number(result1);

    if (result1 == ERROR_SUCCESS) {

        char buffer[39];
        DWORD b = sizeof(buffer);
        LONG result12 = RegGetValueA(hKey, NULL, "HwProfileGuid", RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, buffer, &b);

        if (result12 == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            std::string j;
            LONG result13;
            const std::vector<int> serial1{8, 4, 4, 4, 12};
            std::string l = "{" + gen_random(serial1, "-") + "}";
            const char *p = l.c_str();
            if (p == buffer) {
                j = "{" + gen_random(serial1, "-") + "}";
                const char *i = j.c_str();
                result13 = RegSetValueA(hKey, "HwProfileGuid", REG_SZ, i, sizeof(i));
            } else {
                result13 = RegSetValueA(hKey, "HwProfileGuid", REG_SZ, p, sizeof(p));
            }

            if (result13 == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
                QMessageBox messageBox2;
                messageBox2.critical(0,"Error", "Success");
                messageBox2.setFixedSize(500,200);
            } else {
                QString q = QString::number(result13);
                QMessageBox messageBox2;
                messageBox2.critical(0,"Error", q);
                messageBox2.setFixedSize(500,200);
            }


        } else {
            QString q = QString::number(result12);
            QMessageBox messageBox2;
            messageBox2.critical(0,"Error", q);
            messageBox2.setFixedSize(500,200);
        }


    } else {
        QMessageBox messageBox2;
        messageBox2.critical(0,"Error", q);
        messageBox2.setFixedSize(500,200);
    }
```

My OS is windows 64 bit, the compiler doesn't show any error, and for some reason the function works to create a new value, but not to change the data of an existing one.

I've editted and added the full code so you can see what types of data I am dealing with.

Comment: What does your debugger say when you step through your code?

Comment: @tadman you understood what I meant by that.

Comment: Not in the slightest. If the operating system is relevant to the problem, state the actual operating system you're using.

Comment: @tadman done, but you could have identified what OS I am on just by reading the code.

Comment: I assume you're trying to compare string data here: `if (p == buffer)` That won't work depending on what `buffer` is. Either compare the `std::string` against another string directly or through implicit conversion from a char pointer or use `strcmp`. The first is preferred in C++. Consider putting together a [mcve] which might help you narrow down the problem yourself or fill in the blanks for others to help.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I've added the full code so you can see each variable's type, in this case I think it would just fall on the else case and run normally.

Comment: As @RetiredNinja pointed, `if (p == buffer)` will never be `true`, as those pointers point to different memory locations. Also, `sizeof(p)` is the size of the pointer (8 in this case), and NOT the length of the string.

Comment: @VladFeinstein I've removed this part of the code and replaced sizeof for strlen, but it is still not working

Comment: @El_Sapo_Pepe You say the OS is 64bit, but are you compiling your app as 32bit or 64bit? The Registry has separate areas for 32bit and 64bit apps, so read up about [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/accessing-an-alternate-registry-view) and use the appropriate `KEY_WOW64_(32|64)KEY` flag if needed. Also, `RegSetValueA()` is a legacy 16bit API, you should be using [`RegSetValueExA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa) instead.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvaluea) the last parameter is ignored anyway. Even if you packaged this up as a [mcve] I don't know who would actually run it and try to overwrite that key. You might try [RegSetValueExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa) instead.

Comment: You need to use [`RegSetValueExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa) and call like `BYTE* p = (BYTE*)l.c_str();result13 = RegSetValueExA(hKey, "HwProfileGuid",0, REG_SZ, p, 1024);`.This works for me.

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT since `l` is a `std::string`, you should be using `l.size()+1` instead of `1024` as the data size (`REG_SZ` must include the null terminator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`RegSetValueExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa) and call:

```
BYTE* p = (BYTE*)l.c_str();
result13 = RegSetValueExA(hKey, "HwProfileGuid",0, REG_SZ, p, l.size() + 1);.
```

And it works for me.